Getting oldest/earliest block stored on Ethereum Geth
I would like obtain earliest block that a geth instance has without it replaying to fulfill the history (given in snap sync mode, the instance will attempt to backfill blocks to replay a sufficiently old block).
earliest as an argument in get block no longer returns the correct block (it is 0x0). Is there any other way to get this information?
Related issues:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16411#issuecomment-377176640
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/23405

